# Updating "From" Name in SES with Lambda

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-ses

How do I change the name of who the email is from in my Lambda function with SES?

```
  const params = {
    Destination: {
      ToAddresses: [candidateEmail],
    },
    ReplyToAddresses: [process.env.SES_EMAIL],
    Source: process.env.SES_EMAIL,
    Message: {
      Subject: {
        Charset: "UTF-8",
        Data: `Successful Application`,
      },

      Body: {
        Html: {
          Charset: "UTF-8",
          Data: ""
        },
      },
    },
  };
```

I would like to change **team** to something else

[image: email sample]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to update the source:

```
    Source: `Name <${process.env.SES_EMAIL}>`,
```